# Limits of the Entangle Power?

Tags: savage-worlds

The duration of the entangle power seams to be until you make make your break free roll.

Is the break free roll a standard test ie TN 4 or against the arcane skill roll?

If the Entangle is an Area can you be effected again if you move into the area of effect or is it only those at the time the power was used.

Does the effect come to an end if the caster moves further than Smarts away from the targets?

If the targets keep failing the break free roll are they trapped forever or does the power end at some point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The roll to break free from being entangled is a standard test with TN 4. See [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38230&highlight=entangle).

The entangle effect only affects those in its area of effect at the instant it is cast. Afterwards, characters can enter the area with no problem. See [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18728&highlight=entangle).

The effect only ends when the target succeeds at breaking free. See the previous link [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18728&highlight=entangle).

Of course, as pointed out by SevenSidedDie in the comments below, any or all of the above can be altered by an appropriate trapping, as with any other power in Savage Worlds.

Comment: Any word on the RAW?

Comment: The links given are effectively RAW, as they are from the official answers part of the Savage Worlds forum

Comment: And of course, all of that can be modified by the appropriate Trapping.

Comment: Ah, good point - editing now :o)

Comment: @Yianes The Savage Worlds RAW doesn't try to be comprehensive, so looking always for RAW answers can be frustrating/futile/deceptive.

Comment: Indeed. If you REALLY want to get fiddly then consider the implications of losing all your Agility and Strength linked skills if you are hit by Entangle with a Raise. This means you lose Fighting, so you Parry drops back to 2. Again, its not explicitly stated in the rule book, but implied in the wording of the power

Comment: @SevenSidedDie agreed, but if there actually is something on the RAW it's nice to know.